# iOS Distribution Certificate issue in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

I donwloaded from `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` in `Apple Developers` Provision Profiles and in my Xcode 8 I set `Automatically manage signing`. So Xcode does everything for me.

But when I try to export my build I see this error:

[image]

Can I solve that problem or I should reset it? I have the app in APpStore already, so this is update version and I'm afraid that this will affect the app in AppStore.

Is there a good and safe solution of that problem in Xcode 8?

Comment: Do not worry it will not affect app which is on store

Comment: Have you created certificate from developer apple.com?

Comment: dont reset it , rather create new one and try , it will work like a charm

Comment: you have import signing identity from other mac

Comment: which created on that mac

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I already downloaded certificate and imported into Keychain, but the error stays. Also I created a new Provision Profile. The same thing

Comment: its not about provisioning , its about certicicate

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari but I downloaded existing certificate from App Page and installed it, but error still exists

Comment: then reset it after removing evrythinh

Comment: No, it's the private key associated with the cert. do you have access to the Mac / account that first built the app for the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

This certificate will not affect on the app which is on store ...
try to reset it or download a new certificate from apple developer and import it in your keychain of your mac

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the mac you used to originally build the app for App Store distribution, you can get the private key for the app store distribution certificate.

To do that, go onto the original Mac, open the Keychain Access app, find the iOS Distribution certificate.  If everything is correct, you will see a little triangle that will let you expand the cert to see the private key associated with it.  Right click the key and choose "Export".  Take the .p12 file created when you export the key and open it on the new Mac.  You should see it appear underneath the iOS Distribution cert in the new Mac's Keychain Access app.

If you don't have access, or if your keys / certs are messed up, you can simply generate a new certificate (along with a new key) and tie the iOS Distribution profile to the new certificate. It won't affect your current app in the App Store, as long as it is all done under the same Apple developer account.